# How many years in this context relating to the word "relative to"?

Tags: word-usage

Today, when discussing [this topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/526244/what-is-posttreat-value-in-the-year-of-event), I saw a comment

> By "7 years surrounding the event" they mean the effects in the 2
> years before and the 5 years after the event date. The periods are
> "**relative to**" the first adoption year.

I am wondering whether the commenter said that "7 years surrounding the event" is 8 years, including two years before, 5 years after, and the event year?

Comment: Surely, it would only mean 8 years if the 'event' referred to lasted for a whole year? Otherwise, 'the two years before' is the 24 months ending on the day of the event.

Comment: The event is referred to lasted for a whole year in this case. So, you mean, in this case, it would be 8 years in total?

Comment: If the event lasted a year, and there are 7 years surrounding it, then yes, the total time period is 8 years.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prepositions of time ranges including or excluding the endpoints of the range.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/276017/prepositions-of-time-ranges-including-or-excluding-the-endpoints-of-the-range) Also [Is “until” inclusive or exclusive?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33340/is-until-inclusive-or-exclusive), which is essentially about the same issue.

Comment: What event was it that lasted exactly one year? If that is not the case then @KateBunting comment is the answer. The whole thing is ambiguous without more context.

Comment: @mdewey this is an event study, and regarding imposing a law, we use the year that the law was implemented to be the event year. That's why it is called event year, not event date.